# How to debug iBeacons and Passbook

Tags: ibeacon, passbook, estimote, passkit

I have a pass (which eveyrthing works on, pushs, registrations, pull to refresh, locations, etc) that I've created a Beacons array on. It has a dictionary with a UUID, message, major and minor for an Estimote iBeacon.

```
   "beacons":
  [
    {
      "proximityUUID":"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D",
      "major":5723,
      "minor":49600,
      "relevantText":"Welcome to goldstar"
    }
  ],
```

I can see the iBeacon in the Estimote app, but I get no message on the lock screen for my Passbook. Is there a trick to this? Are there some limits to when the message shows up? I get no errors either installing the pass or in the Xcode console for the device.

I used the passkit builder at https://essentialtechnologies.ca/coffee_demo/ to create an iBeacon demo pass, and it **is** working with my iBeacon. I copy/pasted the code from that pass into my pass, doesn't work.

How does one debug an iBeacon and a Passbook pass?

Comment: Have you tried to enable console logging in Settings > Developer and then connect your iOS device to a Mac running XCode? If there are any problems with the beacons configuration in your pass.json file then you'll see error messages in the console output.

Answer (score 1):

Several things need to be present in order for an iBeacon message to be displayed on the lock screen.

- Bluetooth must be turned on
- Location services must be turned on (Settings -> Privacy -> Location Services)
- Passbook needs to be authorised to use Location Services
- Background App Refresh needs to be turned on (Settings -> General -> Background App Refresh)

This last requirement is usually what is blocking the lock-screen message - fortunately, this requirement has been removed in iOS8.

If all of the above are set, and your beacon still is not showing, can you post a link to the .pkpass bundle that is not working and we can see if we can replicate your issue.