# IOS passbook with Estimote iBeacon

Tags: ios, iphone, ibeacon, estimote

I'm able to create the pkpass containing iBeacon proximityUDID and also, added the same pass to native passbook application within the device(iPhone).

But that pass is not come out to the device screen automatically when we enter in the iBeacon region.

I've tried with the combinations like keeping major and minor (though optional), keeping the native passbook app in background and so on with no success.

Also, for beacon I'm using estimote iBeacon.

Please guide me all.

Comment: wait.. beacon ranging and pass are totaly different... you need to narrow down which part of your program fails and ask specific question related to that issue.

Comment: Swapnil please check the Apple document regarding passbook with integration of iBeacon. It's mentioned that like core location, it's feasible that while creating the passbook provide the beacon information(proximity UUID mandatory) so your pass will open whenever come in range of beacon.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to link a passbook to iBeacons.
See https://developer.apple.com/ibeacon/Getting-Started-with-iBeacon.pdf

Did you check that you meet those requirements? [How to debug iBeacons and Passbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003294/how-to-debug-ibeacons-and-passbook)